# __block variables should be retained in a block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I want to use the results array after performing the block, my question is, should the results array instance be retained because it was originated from a block?

```
__block NSError *error = nil;    
__block NSArray *results;

[moc performBlockAndWait:^(void) {        
    results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; 
    [results retain];
}];
if(results){
   //Do somehting
}
```

Comment: does `executeFetchRequest:error:` return an autoreleased array? My assumption is that it should, and as such you should retain it.

Comment: If you are fetching `NSManagedObjects` (or subclasses) then this will not work and instead you should do all of your processing in `-performBlockAndWait:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be pedantically correct, you would do something like:

```
__block NSError *error = nil;    
__block NSArray *results;

[moc performBlockAndWait:^(void) {        
    results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; 
    [results retain];
    if (!results) [error retain];
}];

if(results){
   //Do somehting
   [results release]; // or not -- assign it to something
} else {
   // Do something with error
   [error release]; // or autorelease
}
```

That is, you want a hard retain maintained from inside the block to outside the block always and regardless of synchronous execution.   That retain must be balanced.

The over-arching rule is all about thread transfer;  you are transferring objects from one thread of execution (wherever the block was executed) to the calling thread.  There must be a hard retain across that transfer of ownership.

Comment: With considerably more details, yes... at least, that would be one interpretation of what you said.  Another would be wrong. ;)  The documentation on this is... lacking.... bug filed.

Comment: you can [error retain] anyway without checking (!results) right? messaging to null is permitted?

Comment: Not in this case, the value of `error` will be undefined unless `results` is nil.

Comment: but if you are initializing error to nil, shouldn't  it be nil unless set by the fetch?

Comment: Nope -- there is no guarantee that `executeFetchRequest:error:` won't set `*error` (internally) to some random value.  The `error` is *only valid if the return value indicates an error occurred*.

Comment: i would have thought explicitly declaring results as nil at the start would be safer. eg "__block NSArray *results = nil;". that way, if performBlockAndWait doesn't call your handler, you aren't dealing with results containing whatever was on the stack when you entered your method.

Comment: __block variables wouldn't work without being initialized to 0 by the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would fall into the general ownership rule for obj-c memory management.  If you need that array, you should claim ownership by retaining it, and releasing it when you are done.

Answer (score 2):

If you receive an autoreleased object, it will normally remain valid for the rest of the current method call and can even be returned as the result of the method. If you need to store it away for future use you must retain it.

Comment: Sorta -- the issue, though, is that it is an object in a block and that block, though synchronously executed, is not necessarily on the same thread.

Comment: This.  Its not safe to assume an autoreleased object will be around at any time in a multithreaded enviornment.